# Cursor not changing to focused element after workspace change

Tags: safari, google-chrome, spaces, cursor

This recently started happening in both Chrome and Safari, but with slightly different behavior in each case.

Chrome:
If I change spaces, and my cursor "lands" over e.g. a textarea in the new space, it does not change to a caret as it should (it stays as an arrow instead). I can use the textarea, but the cursor only rights itself if I do something to force a "refocus" (either move out of and back into the textarea, or right click to instantiate a context menu and then click out of it). Weirdly, the cursor actually *does* change to the caret for a split second after the space change, but then it reverts to the arrow.

Safari:
The bug only happens here if the cursor is moving during the space change. If the cursor is perfectly still, then it switches as expected.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: There's no actual question here to be answered.

Comment: @Tetsujin added an explicit question. I presumed it was implicitly clear that I'd like to stop the erroneous behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this issue was caused by an update to [Bartender](https://www.macbartender.com/). I had been using a very old version (not sure what #) with no issues, and on a whim updated to the latest (4.2.21). After realizing this was the issue, I tried reverting to 4.1.51 (issue persisted), followed by 4.0.48 (issue went away). I'll be reaching out to the developer.